# Python script for reformatting a text file into a csv using Python

Tags: python, string, csv, file-handling

I have been asked to read in a text file containing this:

```
1.

Wicked Stepmother (1989) as Miranda

A couple comes home from vacation to find that their grandfather has …

2.

Directed By William Wyler (1988) as Herself

During the Golden Age of Hollywood, William Wyler was one of the …

3.

Whales of August, The (1987) as Libby Strong

Drama revolving around five unusual elderly characters, two of whom …

4.

As Summers Die (1986) as Hannah Loftin

Set in a sleepy Southern Louisiana town in 1959, a lawyer, searches …
```

and to create a .csv output file that looks like this:

```
1,Wicked Stepmother ,1989, as Miranda,A couple comes home from vacation …
2,Directed By William Wyler ,1988, as Herself,During the Golden Age of …
3,"Whales of August, The ",1987, as Libby Strong,Drama revolving around five…
```

I know that if I can slice the lines apart, then I can add them back together again with commas in between them and then write those strings into my output file. My problem is with the format. For the numbers I would only want:

```
line1=stringname[0]+','
line2= stringname[:stringname.find('(')-1]+','+stringname[stringname.find('(')+1:stringname.find(')')-1]+','+stringname[stringname.find(')')+1:]
```

no change to line3 then write into the file

```
result=line1+line2+line3
```

The problem is I have no idea which line I am parsing at any given time. I was thinking maybe something in a for loop which makes sure I parse the code in groups of 3 lines at a time, but I am not sure how to manage the file handling at the same time. I am also not sure how to prevent the loop from going over the end of the program.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service

Comment: you would need regexes to extract title, year and the "as" part. That would be the hardest part. Rest is piece of cake. Show us your attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done easily using a regular expression but I am guessing you do not wish to use that.

Instead the problem can be solved by reading the file in a line at a time and deciding if the line starts with a number followed by a `.`. If it does, start you start building up a list of lines until you find the next number.

Using Python's `int()` function will attempt to convert a string into a number. The `find('.')` function attempts to locate the end of the number.

If the returned string is not a number, it causes a `ValueError` exception to be raised. In this case, add the line to the list of lines.

If there was a number, first write any existing entry to the `csv` file, and then start a new entry.

At the end, there will not be a final number line to trigger the next write, so add another call to write the final row to the csv.

For example:

```
import csv        

with open('text.txt') as f_input, open('output.csv', 'wb') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    entry = []

    for line in f_input:
        line = line.strip()    # Remove the trailing newline

        if len(line):          # Does the line containing anything?
            try:
                number = int(line[:line.find('.')])

                if len(entry):
                    csv_output.writerow(entry)
                entry = [number]
            except ValueError:
                entry.append(line)

    csv_output.writerow(entry)
```

Python's `csv` library is used to take a list and automatically add the necessary commas between entries when writing to the csv output file. If an entry contains a comma, it will automatically add quotes.